# php soap client with nested childs

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to figure how to create this soap envelope using soap client

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<m:sendDataExtraccionTraza
xmlns:m="http://www.mop.cl/controlextraccion/xsd/datosExtraccion/SendDataExtraccionRequest">
<m:codigoDeLaObra>OB-0303-204</m:codigoDeLaObra>
<m:timeStampOrigen>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</m:timeStampOrigen>
</m:sendDataExtraccionTraza>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:sendDataExtraccionRequest
xmlns:m="http://www.mop.cl/controlextraccion/xsd/datosExtraccion/SendDataExtraccionRequest">
<m:dataExtraccionSubterranea>
<m:fechaMedicion>17-08-1967</m:fechaMedicion>
<m:horaMedicion>00:01:01</m:horaMedicion>
<m:totalizador>1234567891</m:totalizador>
<m:caudal>12345678.12</m:caudal>
<m:nivelFreaticoDelPozo >12345678.12</m:nivelFreaticoDelPozo >
</m:dataExtraccionSubterranea>
</m:sendDataExtraccionRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Tried making it like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));

$ns = 'http://www.mop.cl/controlextraccion/xsd/datosExtraccion/SendDataExtraccionRequest';

$headerbody = array('codigoDeLaObra' => POZO_PRUEBA,
'timeStampOrigen' => '2020-01-01T09:30:47Z');

$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'sendDataExtraccionTraza', $headerbody);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$args = array( "fechaMedicion" => "10-10-2020",
    "horaMedicion" => "10:01:01",
    "totalizador" => "1234567891",
    "caudal" => "12345678.12",
    "nivelFreaticoDelPozo" => "12345678.12"
);

$res  = $client->__soapCall('sendDataExtraccionOp', [
new SoapParam("10-10-2020", "fechaMedicion"),
new SoapParam("10:01:01", "horaMedicion"),
new SoapParam("1234567891", "totalizador"),
new SoapParam("12345678.12", "caudal"),
new SoapParam("1", "nivelFreaticoDelPozo")]);
```

I am getting an error as result, so i've managed to htmlentities the $client->__getLastRequest() and seeing this outcome

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mop.cl/controlextraccion/xsd/datosExtraccion/SendDataExtraccionRequest">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns1:sendDataExtraccionTraza>
<ns1:codigoDeLaObra>OB-0202-251</ns1:codigoDeLaObra>
<ns1:timeStampOrigen>2020-01-01T09:30:47Z</ns1:timeStampOrigen>
</ns1:sendDataExtraccionTraza>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:sendDataExtraccionRequest/>
<horaMedicion>10:01:01</horaMedicion>
<totalizador>1234567891</totalizador>
<caudal>12345678.12</caudal>
<nivelFreaticoDelPozo>1</nivelFreaticoDelPozo>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am missing a <m:dataExtraccionSubterranea> parent inside the senddataExtraccionRequest, and i can't figure how to create it.
Any hint?

Comment: Why don't you use `$args`?

Comment: $args as they are stated returned empty body, that's why i did the soapParams